# How to make Ms SQL CLR binary code fixed if there was no changes during the build

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, msbuild

I added some C# code to SQL project. For the first build and deployment it went smoothly, however after the second run of build/deploy I noticed that the CLR was ammended on SQL server side even there was no changes to C# code.

Is there a way to have make the build to generate the same binary each time it builds assembly from C# code if there was no changes in it? As I would like to have CLR code changes to be deployed only if there were changes made to C# code, not the each time the build creates new and different binary for the assmebly.

Answer (score 0):

> only if there were changes made to C# code, not the each time the
> build creates new and different binary for the assmebly.

Does the assembly indicates `xx.dll`? If so, as I know for C# code, msbuild call the `CoreCompile` target to compile the C# code to output assembly. And the `CoreCompile` target will execute and create new assembly only when part of the input files are newer than output files.

According to your description, it seems the build engine will create new assembly even there're no changes made to the input source file for CoreCompile target, I suggest you change the `Msbuild build output verbosity`(Tools=>Options=>Project and Solutions=>Build and Run) to **Detailed** and check the build out log:

[image]

Then you can find what are the input files for the target(Ctrl+F to find the target) in your current datebase project. And locate the cause that the build engine always create new assembly in your machine.